# Alternative to ViewPager in Android

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-support-library

I would like to build some Activity which consists of several screens (Fragments) with one `GridView` in each. This Activity uses `ViewPager` from the Support library.
This is working pretty well.

When clicking one item in one of the `GridView`s, the page should automatically turn (flip) and show more details on that item.

Both the ViewPager and the Flip transitions are working pretty well with one cosmetic issue:
When flipping the `GridView` Fragment to the details view Fragment, the `GridView` is not animated. The flipping in details Fragment is perfectly animated and is flying in, but the `GridView` which should do a fly-out transition is not animated at all.

I'm not an expert on Android programming, but I guess that the root cause of this behaviour is that the `ViewPager` is part of the Support library and thus does not support this custom animation transaction.

Could I be right?
Is there an easy-to-use alternative to `ViewPager` which also supports custom animations?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is an answer, but ViewPager does support custom animations.  See http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer

Answer (score 2):

If you changing Fragments in your app, than you should use FragemntTransaction instead of ViewPager. With this you can customize the animation of the new and the old Fragment.

For example:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
      .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom, 
                           R.anim.slide_out_to_top,
                           R.anim.slide_in_from_top, 
                           R.anim.slide_out_to_bottom)
      .replace(R.id.MainLayout, newFragment, NewFragment.TAG).commit();
```

But here is an article about the :
[flip animation](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html)

You can use the [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/)
lib, which backports the ObjectAnimator and ValueAnimator

Comment: That sounds like the answer. Can I also handle swipe gestures between two Fragments with `FragmentTransaction`s?

Comment: With FragmentTransaction the swipe is not an easy option.